# How to set devise_for namespace::user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have user model with namespace eg: 
app/models/v1/user.rb

I know if 
app/models/user.rb
we can do

```
devise_for :user
```

but with namespace
I don't know how 
to set devise_for that user object (with namespace)

```
devise_for 'v1/user'
```

rake routes ok but devise helper not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `devise_for` method supports `path` and `class_name` options.

You can do something like this:

```
devise_for :users, path: 'v1/user', class_name: "V1::User"
```

Comment: That means I can do ~~~ devise_for :user, path: 'v1/user,  class_name "V1:: User", controllers: {sessions: 'v1/sessions'} ~~~ but I like to have another controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/sessions'}. It's not work perhap you can help /Thks

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. You can specify any controller in `controllers` option: `devise_for :user, path: "v1/user", class_name "V1:: User", controllers: {sessions: 'v1/sessions', omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/sessions'}`

Comment: Thanks, It work. It might help other please answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277724/how-to-redirect-devise-for-controller-to-other-than-default-devise