# how to redirect devise_for controller to other than default devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have

```
devise_for :user, path: 'v1/user', class_name: "V1::User",controllers: {sessions: 'v1/sessions'
```

I like to have it redirect all not just sessions including :omniauth_callbacks to v1/sessions

or something like this

devise_for :user, path: 'v1/user', class_name: "V1::User",controllers: {sessions: 'v1/sessions'}, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/sessions'}

it will errors

> warning: key :controllers is duplicated and overwritten on line 16

Comment: I think you can just add another option the the controllers hash, i.e.:

`{ sessions: 'v1/sessions', omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/sessions' }`

Comment: Yes it work. Would you please answer from you comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you can just add another option to the controllers hash:

`{ sessions: 'v1/sessions', omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/sessions' }`

Answer (score 1):

Just include `omniauth_callbacks` key in the controller hash.

```
devise_for :user, path: 'v1/user', class_name: "V1::User",controllers: {sessions: 'v1/sessions', omniauth_callbacks: 'v1/sessions'}
```

Now your redirects for both email login and oauth login will be to `v1/sessions`

Comment: I can only accept the first answer from comment. Thanks anyway